# Generic type for static method

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way I can make the static method `toObject` generic by passing the T class and return type T?

```java
public class JsonUtil {

    private JsonUtil() {

    }

    public static Object toObject(String jsonString, Class clazz, boolean unwrapRootValue) throws TechnicalException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        if (unwrapRootValue) mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException("Exception while converting JSON to Object", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JsonConverter would be a much better name for your class than JsonUtil.  “Util” says nothing about what a class does.

Comment: I agree with the naming convention @VGR

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just specify a generic type parameter on the method itself, and use it for both the return type and the `clazz` parameter:

```
public static <T> T toObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz,
        boolean unwrapRootValue) throws TechnicalException {

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class JsonUtil {

    private JsonUtil() {

    }

    public static <T> T toObject(String jsonString, Class<? extends T> clazz, boolean unwrapRootValue) throws TechnicalException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        if (unwrapRootValue) mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException("Exception while converting JSON to Object", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you removed  `Class<? super T>`, however, `Class<? extends T>` might actually be useful. I haven't thought it through enough to determine if it would have any utility when casting `toObject` as a method reference.

Comment: No need to cast the result of `mapper.readValue()`. It's already generic.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen Thanks alot!  Answer has been fixed.